# Trying to check array data with if statement

Tags: c++, arrays, function, if-statement

I'm trying to check if the users input data falls within the range i want. so far i have it like this:

```
void getPlayersNumbers(int playerArray[], int size) {

cout << "Please enter 5 numbers between 1-5\n";

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    cin >> playerArray[i];

    if (playerArray[i] < 1 || playerArray[i] > 5) {
        cout << "Please enter numbers between 1 and 5\n";
    }
}
}
```

now if they enter a number less than 1 or greater than 5 the message shows up. The only problem is i can still only input 5 numbers total even if one of them is out of the range and the message shows up. what should i do so that the function will only end if they enter 5 numbers that are within my set range?

Comment: Try [explaining the logic in your code to your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). I'm sure that your rubber duck might have some ideas.

Comment: Don't use a fixed `for` loop but a `while` instead, with a counter for correct inputs only.

Comment: In the case where the number is out of range the program should ask for it again. You can accomplish this by replacing your loop body with a call to a function that asks for and returns a number in the correct range, where that function uses a loop to ask repeatedly until it gets an OK number.

Comment: Tip 1: instead of raw arrays use `std::vector`.

Comment: Tip 2: for a function that produces a result just *return* that result.

Answer (score 1):

Consider what you are doing:

1. You get input.
2. You put that input into your array.
3. You check whether input was smaller than 1 or bigger than 5
4. Go back to **1.**

Comment: This really made me think of my problem a different way and now i got it. Thanks!